# Django Crispy Forms Rendering Issue 'cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence'

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Struggling to figure this one out. I've seen several issues where this error code shows up but all seem to have to do with data not being passed into the context for the template to render. I know my data is getting through to the template. Crispy forms must be doing something behind the scenes that is throwing me off? Weird thing is this literally worked 20 minutes ago. I don't know what I could have changed that would have affected this.

Here is my view:

```
class ContactListView(View):

    template = 'support_tracker/contact_list.html'

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        staff_id = kwargs.pop('staff_id',False)

        if staff_id:
            staff = Staff.objects.get(pk=staff_id)
        else:
            staff = request.user.staff
        contact_list = staff.contacts.all()

        search_term = request.GET.get('search_term',False)
        sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by',False)
        filter_by = request.GET.get('filter_by',False)

        ##applying search term to determine contact_list
            ...
        ##

        ##sorting of contact_list
            ....
        ##

        ##filtering of contact_list
            ....
        ##

        search_form = SearchForm()
        sort_form = ContactListSortForm()
        filter_form = FilterByStageForm()

        ##pagination to determine contacts
            ...
        ##

        context = {
        'staff':staff,
        'contacts':contacts,
        'search_form':search_form,
        'sort_form':sort_form,
        'filter_form':filter_form,
        'filter_by':filter_by,
        'search_term':search_term,
        'sort_by':sort_by,
        }

        print context

        return render(request,self.template,context)
```

My Forms:

```
##forms.py
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search_term = forms.CharField(max_length=30,label='')

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(SearchForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'GET'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            InlineField('search_term',placeholder='Search'),
            Submit('','Go',css_class='btn btn-primary'),
            )

class FilterByStageForm(forms.Form):
        filter_by = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_stage_option_list(),required=False)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(FilterByStageForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'GET'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            InlineField('filter_by',placeholder='Filter By'),
            Submit('','Filter',css_class='btn btn-primary'),
            )

class ContactListSortForm(forms.Form):
    sort_by = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(##options),required=False)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ContactListSortForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.form_method = 'GET'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            InlineField('sort_by',placeholder='Sort By'),
            Submit('','Sort',css_class='btn btn-primary'),
            )
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'co_tools/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class='container'>
    <div class='col-md-3 well'>
        <h3><u>Search:</u></h3>


        ## This is the part that trips it up. If I take the forms out, the rest of the page loads fine
        {% crispy search_form %}
        {% crispy sort_form %}
        {% crispy filter_form %}


        <a href='/support/new_contact/' class='btn btn-primary'>New Contact</a>
    </div>

    ...body...

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The full traceback

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/support/contact_list/

Django Version: 1.10.2
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'support_tracker',
 'donor_reports',
 'staff',
 'financial_reports']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\...\project\support_tracker\templates\support_tracker\contact_list.html, error at line 8
   cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence   1 : {% extends 'co_tools/base.html' %}
   2 : {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
   3 : 
   4 : {% block content %}
   5 : <div class='container'>
   6 :  <div class='col-md-3 well'>
   7 :      <h3><u>Search:</u></h3>
   8 :       {% crispy form %} 
   9 :      <a href='/support/new_contact/' class='btn btn-primary'>New Contact</a>
   10 :     </div>
   11 :     <div class='col-md-9'>
   12 :         <table class='table table-condensed table-hover'>
   13 :             <thead>
   14 :                 <th>Contact Name</th>
   15 :                 <th>Phone Number</th>
   16 :                 <th>Email</th>
   17 :                 <th>Street Address</th>
   18 :                 <th>City</th>


Traceback:

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\...\project\support_tracker\views.py" in get
  185.      return render(request,self.template,context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  70.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_tags.py" in render
  215.         c = self.get_render(context)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_tags.py" in get_render
  126.         response_dict = self.get_response_dict(helper, context, is_formset)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\templatetags\crispy_forms_tags.py" in get_response_dict
  160.         attrs = helper.get_attributes(template_pack=self.template_pack)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\helper.py" in get_attributes
  364.         if self.form_action:

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\crispy_forms\helper.py" in form_action
  237.             return reverse(self._form_action)

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  344.             self._populate()

File "C:\...\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _populate
  217.                                     dict(defaults, **pattern.default_kwargs),

Exception Type: TypeError at /support/contact_list/
Exception Value: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So just as an update for more info, I'm finding that I get this error every single time I used `{% crispy form %}` to render a form in a template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved the issue. I have no clue why this particular bit of code was causing the problem though.

In my urls.py, I had added the following four url expressions...

from django.conf.urls import url, include
import views

```
urlpatterns = [
     ...
    #meeting urls
    url(r'^record_meeting/(?P<meeting_id>[0-9]+)/',views.EditMeetingView.as_view(),{'record':True}),
    url(r'^record_meeting/$',views.EditMeetingView.as_view(),{'record':True}),
    url(r'^edit_meeting/(?P<meeting_id>[0-9]+)/',views.EditMeetingView.as_view(),{'record':False}),
    url(r'^add_meeting/$',views.EditMeetingView.as_view()),
]
```

The fourth one was originally `url(r'^add_meeting/$',views.EditMeetingView.as_view(),{'record':False})`, which apparently, based on trial and error, was causing the issue. After removing the additional arguments, the problem went away. Does anyone know why this was an issue in the first place? I still don't understand.